# Visual Studio Code Python debugger running significantly slower when using random.uniform() compared with random.random()

Tags: python, random, vscode-debugger

My Python version is 3.8.2 and I use Visual Studio Code 1.43.1 to write my code. 
I'm estimating the value of pi using the Monte Carlo method.

It turns out that when I use random.random() to generate random numbers, it takes me roughly 1.4s in release mode and 1.6s in the debugger. But when I switch the random.random() to random.uniform(0,1),  it costs roughly 1.9s in the release mode and 6.5s in the debugger.

I suppose it is reasonable that the running time will increase because each time I generate a number, the uniform function will do an additional calculation. But why is there only a slight increase in the release mode, while the time used in the debugger increases by nearly 3 times? What is the mechanism behind this phenomenon? Or is there something wrong with my debugger?

My code is listed below. I have deleted all breakpoints in the debugger. Since I'm a beginner for Python, I didn't do much change in the setting.

```
from random import random,uniform
from time import perf_counter
LEN=1000000
COUNT=0
start=perf_counter()
for i in range(LEN):
    x,y=uniform(0,1),uniform(0,1)  #switch between random() and uniform(0,1)
    dist=pow(x**2+y**2,0.5)
    if dist<=1.0:
        COUNT+=1
pi=4*COUNT/LEN
end=perf_counter()
print("pi={:10f}".format(pi))
print("time consumed:{:f}".format(end-start))
```

Comment: Note that `uniform` takes two more parameters than `random` does.  Maybe the overhead in storing and maintaining the parameters by the debugger explains the time difference.

Comment: It's probably related to the fact that `random.uniform` is the only thing you call that's implemented in Python instead of C, so it's the only thing the debugger can actually debug outside of the parts you've written.

Comment: I self-defined a new function with the same definition as `uniform`. This time it runs as slow as using the built-in `uniform`. Does it confirm that it is the two parameters added in the overhead that makes the difference?@PeterO.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand the relationship between vscode Python debugger and C. Could you tell me a bit more about that or where to find relevant information? @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: I also wrote this program in C and use gdb as the debugger. (To get a commensurate running time, I increased the loop size to 50000000.) This time the use of gdb didn't increase the running time as Python debugger did.  On account of this, I wonder whether the truth that the addition of 2 parameters could make such a dramatic change is an innate characteristic of this specific python debugger or python language itself?@PeterO.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try pypy with visual studio code python extension，it's can improve python debugger performance.

Comment: Can you please explain the issue?